# VK Callback API на один запрос много ответов

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, вконтакте

Пишу на PHP бота для паблика ВК, и вот что происходит, когда пользователь пишет сообщение, появляется событие message_new, и когда отвечает бот, должно появляться message_reply. Но вместо одного message_reply, их приходит очень много. На скриншоте показываю пример. Кто сталкивался с этим, подскажите, в чём может быть причина? Странно что они продолжают приходить спустя много часов даже.

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Помимо всего этого, есть еще "Неудавшиеся запросы"
И вот ответ сервера, не совсем понимаю где ошибка

> HTTP/1.1 200 OK
>   Date: Wed, 29 Mar 2017 02:21:52 GMT
>   Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
>   Transfer-Encoding: chunked
>   Connection: keep-alive
>   Server: awex
>   X-Xss-Protection: 1; mode=block
>   X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
>   X-Request-ID: d8c400366020cfe9e2c0a7ba654ddccb

Answer (score 4):

А в теле ответа от сервера вы возвращаете строку `ok`, как это требуется в документации и показано в [официальном примере](https://vk.com/dev/callback_api?f=3.%20%D0%9F%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%80%20%D0%B8%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F)?

> **Обратите внимание**: после получения уведомления Ваш сервер должен возвращать строку "ok" и статус HTTP 200. Если сервер несколько раз подряд вернет ошибку, Callback API временно перестанет отправлять на него уведомления.

Comment: В конце case 'message_new' у меня: //Возвращаем "ok" серверу Callback API 
    echo('ok'); 

break;  Так что да, возвращаю

Comment: @idriverx а вы проверяли, что возвращается ТОЛЬКО ok и ничего больше?

Comment: @andreymal у меня echo больше нигде нет в коде

Comment: @idriverx а это ничего не значит, может ещё какие-нибудь варнинги пхп печатаются)

Comment: Исходя из ответа, что вы кинули, у вас ok не возвращается. И то, что у вас в коде всего один echo не значит, что код до него вообще доходит. Может он падает до этого.

Answer (score 1):

На все запросы Callback API нужно отвечать "ОК"
[image: C оф. документации]

```
header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");
    echo 'OK';
```

У меня было такая же проблема из-за того, что "ОК" повторялось дважды (пишу драйвер для [botman.io](https://botman.io))

Answer (score 0):

Столкнулся с той же проблемой. Установил код из документации ВК, но он всё равно дублировал ответы. Методом единоразового тыка я решил проблему. Надеюсь, Вам тоже поможет)

Это:

```
$request_params = array(
        'message' => "Hello, {$user_name}!",
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'v' => '5.0'
    );
```

Поменял на это:

```
$request_params = array(
        'message' => "Hello, {$user_name}!",
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'access_token' => $token,
        'read_state' => 1,
        'v' => '5.0'
    );
```

Мне кажется, это не логично, и такой код не должен решать нашу проблему. Но у меня теперь все отлично)

Comment: ой костыль то какой)) у меня решилось в настройке паблика, в пункте "Работа с АПИ" -> Callback API -> Типы событий я оставил только ВХОДЯЩИЕ СООБЩЕНИЯ. На то время когда я писал этот пост, у меня также был выставлен чекбокс и на "исходящие сообщения", и после того как я убрал чекбокс с исходящих проблема пропала)

Comment: Это теперь не работает) Надо добавить еще статус 200 "header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");" перед "echo('ok');"

Answer (score 0):

Точно такая же ошибка была. Долго разбирался, в итоге решение нашлось вот таким способом:

```
switch ($data->type) {
.... Разные типы ответа "case 'message_new': и прочее", 
       " default:
            echo('ok');"
         }
```

Видимо приходят от *api* какие-то незадокументированные типы ответов. Короче говоря, `default` тоже надо обрабатывать.

Answer (score 0):

Корочее.... у кого до сих пор не работает, добавьте(см на картинку).
Так вот. message_reply приходит когда смс прочитано, но default или else не помогают надо прямо на него указывать, и еще, такие ответы с заголовком и echo нужно после каждого запроса.[image: Код:]

Comment: Я понимаю, что эмоции, но хорошо бы структурировать свой ответ

Answer (score 0):

Ваш скрипт должен ответить ok и завершится в течение ~2с, иначе вк считает, что запрос не дошел. 
Если у вас web сервер apache или nginx, то для решения этой проблемы вы можете отправлять вк OK и разрывать соединение, не дожидаясь завершения скрипта. Используйте эту функцию:

```
    public function sendOK() {
    set_time_limit(0);
    ini_set('display_errors', 'Off');

    // для Nginx
    if (is_callable('fastcgi_finish_request')) {
        session_write_close();
        fastcgi_finish_request();
        return True;
    }
    // для Apache
    ignore_user_abort(true);

    ob_start();
    header('Content-Encoding: none');
    header('Content-Length: 2');
    header('Connection: close');
    echo 'ok';
    ob_end_flush();
    flush();
    return True;
}
```

Но у вас написано, Server: awex. Скорее всего вы используете 000.webhost, он слишком долгий и не подходит для ботов, так же вы не сможете воспользоваться функцией выше для отправки ok и принудительного закрытия соединения.