# Бот вк на php, повторные ответы

Tags: php, vkontakte-api, бот

Написал бота на PHP для вконтакте. Проблема в том, что на одно сообщение приходит несколько ответов.

Как можно это исправить?

```php
$data = json_decode(file_get_contents('php://input'));

  switch($data->type)
  {
    case 'confirmation':

    echo $return;

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    break;

    case 'message_new':


    $text = $data->object->text;
    $user_id = $data->object->from_id;
    $user_info = json_decode(file_get_contents("https://api.vk.com/method/users.get?user_ids={$user_id}&access_token={$key}&v=5.101"));
    $user_name = $user_info->response[0]->first_name;

    $array = array(
        'message' => "Привет, {$user_name}",
        'access_token' => $key,
        'user_id' => $user_id,
        'v' => '5.101',
        'random_id' => rand(),
        'read_state' => '1'
    );

    $ch = curl_init('https://api.vk.com/method/messages.send');

    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $array);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, "POST");

    curl_exec($ch);
    curl_close($ch);

    header("HTTP/1.1 200 OK");

    echo ('OK');

    break;

  }
```

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/704989/285292